# Dynamic find and change value of column

Tags: vba, excel

I have to make simple anonmizer in VBA Excel.

[image]

I have document as on picture up. I have to find dynamicly column with "code":

I am opening file:

```
Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath, ReadOnly:=True)
```

and looking for column with "code"

```
For Each ws In wbSrc.Sheets
'find word "code" to set column number
 Set r = ws.Cells.Find(What:="code", After:=ws.Range("A1"), 
LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
 xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False)
```

If we find write number to variable:

```
 If Not r Is Nothing Then
            codeCol= r.Column
```

And know i dont know how to select everything below "code" header. 
There will be code with about 16 number which I want to cut

```
Left(rowHere,6)
```

Ofcourse in every sheet number of not blank rows in column will be dynamic. So everything I need is reference to row below "code" and for loop which change value in every not blank row.

Comment: in variable codeCol i have only number not specific cell e.g "D3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the last row with data and then loop, something like below will do that:

```
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, codeCol).End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column codeCol

For i = r.row + 1 to LastRow 'loop from row below "code" to last on given column
    If ws.Cells(i, codeCol) <> "" then 'if cell is not blank
        ws.Cells(i, codeCol).Value = Left(ws.Cells(i, codeCol).Value, 6)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Ok I am almost there. So how to save changes e.g in another file? ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "deleted.xlsx" but he asking me to save for everyrecord :/

Comment: Save your workbook outside of the For Loop (after `Next i`), once you made all your changes...

Comment: Thats what i am trying to do, but program asking to make changes for infinity :D

Comment: @Buckethead without having a look at your full code it is very difficult for me to formulate an answer, could you update your original question with the  code where you are trying to save?

Comment: @Buckethead, please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure. Thanks again ;)